# Unable to connect to database as created user - ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user

Tags: mysql

I have a redhat linux server with root password A

When setting up MySQL, I gave it a password B (not A)

I need to connect to 'mydatabase' as user 'myusername'

Listing users shows:

```
mysql> select user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mysql.user;
...
| localhost | root            | qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq1 |
| localhost | myusername      | qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq2 |
...
```

But I cant seem to connect to it from the command line:

```
# mysql --database=mydatabase --user=myusername --host=localhost --password=qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq2
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' to database 'mydatabase'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you granted *myusername* permissions on *mydatabase*?

The command you would do that with is `GRANT ALL ON mydatabase.* TO 'myusername'@'localhost';` (log into MySQL as root when doing this).

Then flush the privileges with `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` so it takes effect.